# How to automatically generate new input fields by filling previous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

To be as simple as I can:
I have condition where I do not know where I'm going to have 3 or more input elements (type of "text") and I'm looking for solution which will generate 4th input type text when I start to fill 3th input field with characters, and so on.

Something similar Adminer have for adding new columns when creating/altering database:
[image]

here you click on + to add new input and x to remove it. This would also be good to me.
How to achieve that/what library should I use?

Comment: please pop some code into this question.  It's difficult to tell what you want without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: I'm asking if there is library for that, I couldn't find such functionality in, for example jquery UI

Comment: no, this is a simple enough problem that doesn't qualify as a standard UX problem, so I think most libraries leave it to you to pop in those 4 lines of code.  also, if you're new to javascript, you may try twitter-bootstrap rather than jquery-ui.  It gives you a  more complete (debatably) front-end framework, looks better, and is easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone full row, and append it to parent table. Have a look at jQuery [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Sample code:

```
$('#yourtableid').on('click', '.add', function() {

   // clone first row
   var row = $('#yourtableid tbody tr:first').clone();

   // reset inputs 
   row.find('input[type!=button]').val('');

   // append cloned row 
   $('#yourtableid tbody').append(row);

});
```

Live [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/icetob/4/edit).

EDIT: To add row automatically when filled some text in last row, you can go with:

```
$('#tbl').on('change', 'input', function() {

  // check that some input was entered and that it is in the last tr
  if($(this).val() != '' &&
     $(this).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
    addRow();
  }
});
```

Comment: This explains the irrelevant example given in the question, but doesn't really answer the problem: "I'm looking for solution which will generate 4th input type text when I start to fill 3th input field with characters, and so on."

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what you're trying to get without a code sample, but do you want something like this?

HTML:

```
<input type='text' />
```

JS:

```
$('input').on( 'change', function() {
    $(this).after( '<input type="text" />' );
    $('input').off( 'change' );
});
```

jsFiddle is down and jsBin can't handle the extra load, but [here](http://jsbin.com/eqoxip/1/)'s a demo.

Comment: whatever floats your boat.

Comment: LOL! If by that, you mean valid HTML, then that definitely floats my boat.

Comment: @BenM

1.  non-self-closing input elements are perfectly valid HTML5, as is every variety of non-self-closing tag.

2.  I didn't specify a doctype.  if this is strict XHTML, the tags _can't_ be self-closing.

3.  is everything alright?  you seem a little upset.